# Union types and conditional type behave differently when used with or without generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Consider this case:

```
type RemoveTypesFromUnion<N, K> = N extends K ? never : N

type Strings = 'string1' | 'string2' | 'string3'    
type WithoutGenerics = Strings extends 'string2' | 'string3' ? never : Strings // 'string1' | 'string2' | 'string3'
type WithGenerics = RemoveTypesFromUnion<Strings, 'string2' | 'string3'> // 'string1'
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2B7AbhAKuCBnAYgJ0XgFUA7AS0RIB4A5AGigGkA%20KAXihqggA9gISAEyxMoAfigkIqPFABcnALAAoFaEhQAysDxkSAcxEcA5Fh179ARmNQAPlFPmDAJhv3HugwGYbUP2swoAHUyYAALRABXYABxAQhdAGMjLSdDbj4BYQczT31XOxy0n3FJaQT5VLyRAHoaqAAiXItLBsKmtOc2%20w68rwaAjRDwuKkklLgkVAxIXAJickoqbWqGDwsC92bvY1Y6xu2rBqA)

The `WithoutGenerics` type resolves to `'string1' | 'string2' | 'string3'` because `'string1' | 'string2' | 'string3'` is not assignable to `'string2' | 'string3'` so the conditional expression evaluates to `Strings`.

On the other hand, the `WithGenerics` type resolves to `'string1'` which is actually the union of the results of every type of the `Strings` union, after having been passed in the conditional type:

- Does `'string1'` extend `'string2' | 'string3'`? No: `N extends K ? never : N` gives `'string1'`
- Does `'string2'` extend `'string2' | 'string3'`? Yes: `N extends K ? never : N` gives `never`
- Does `'string3'` extend `'string2' | 'string3'`? Yes: `N extends K ? never : N` gives `never`

The final type is the union of these three types `'string1' | never | never` which gives `'string1'`.

Now my question is: why `WithoutGenerics` and `WithGenerics` would resolve to different types? There is no room for type inference as I specified `N` and `K` myself so why aren't they equivalent?

Comment: Conditional types distribute across unions in the type being checked if and only if that type is a generic type parameter. See the answer to the other question for more info.

Comment: Didn't know that particularity of the conditional types. Thanks 